# python passing command line argument with-in program

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I have below python program takes argument from command line.

```
import argparse
import sys

choice=['orange','apple', 'grapes', 'banna']

def select():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='one', description='name test')
    parser.add_argument(
        'fname',
        action="store",
        type=str,
        choices=choice,
        help="furits name")

    args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:2])

    print 'selected name {0}\n'.format(args.fname)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    select()
```

this works

```
 python s.py apple
selected name apple
```

How can inline argument with-in main function. I tried this but its not working.

change main line this.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0]='apple'
    select()
```

getting below error.

> ```
> usage: one [-h] {orange,apple,grapes,banna}
> one: error: too few arguments
> ```

How can I achieve this in argument?

thanks
-SR

Comment: The default action for `parse_args` is to use `sys.argv[1:]`.  `sys.argv[0]` is used as the default `prog` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your index is wrong `sys.argv[0]` will be the path of the python script.  What you want is:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        sys.argv.append("apple")
    select()
```

But, this is a weird way of doing things.  After a bit more thought, this occurred to me:

```
choice=['orange','apple', 'grapes', 'banna']

def select():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='one', description='name test')
    parser.add_argument(
        'fname',
        nargs='?',
        default='apple',
        action="store",
        type=str,
        choices=choice,
        help="furits name")

    args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:2])

    print 'selected name {0}\n'.format(args.fname)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    select()
```

Note the `nargs='?'` and `default='apple'` additions to the call to add_argument().  These make the parameter optional and set the default value to "apple" if no argument is supplied.

Comment: @BogdanMarginean you are correct, my testing was poor, corrected.

Comment: @sfgroups No problem